# spring data rest: можно ли отменить операцию по условию?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

У меня есть entity с подключенным spring-boot-starter-data-rest.

```
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class UserEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeDelete
    public void handleUserDelete(User user) {}
}
```

Возможно ли как то, допустим с помощью хендлера, перед выполнением операции проверить условие и если оно не выполнено, то отменить операцию? Если в нем выкинуть exception то операция прервется?